# Access file from Mac Public Folder or shared folder using iPad Application by Bonjour Service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.5, bonjour

i want to Access file from Mac Public Folder or any other shared folder that is connected to iPad Application. using Bonjour i am able to get list of connected Mac in application i have download source code from below two links:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BonjourWeb/Introduction/Intro.html 
http://blog.haurus.com/?p=342

but now i want to access file from shred folder of that connected Mac using Bonjour. Any sample code or idea for that then reply here.

Thanks in Advance.